# Angular 15 - ng generate environments

Tags: angular, ng-generate

How can I resolve the error "*Error: A collection and schematic is required during execution*" that I encountered while attempting to generate environments automatically using the *ng generate environments* command in Angular (version 15.0.5)?

The Angular documentation at https://angular.io/guide/build did not provide a solution to this specific issue, and I am a novice in Angular.

I cannot find solution to this anywhere, I was reading some blogs but still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to 15.1

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24381#issuecomment-1351557054

After the release of Angular CLI 15.1, a generation schematic will be available to add environment files for all existing build configurations within a project.
Example usage: ng generate environments